# Best Git strategy for a project on multiple platforms

Tags: git, version-control, github

Hi there i have an application that has several different applications these are:

1. "Client Server" Application (java)
2. "License Server" Application (java) (i am deploying this app to heroku with git)
3. "An Auto-update application" (java)
4. "Client Application" (objective-c)

all i know about git is standard commiting commands and things like that and i have a github membership with 5 private repositories. So i am wondering what is the best way to utilize git on this? Possible answers are:

1. Create a single git repo and put those seperate projects in "branches" ?
2. Create a single git repo and just put those projects in seperate fodlers?
3. Just put them into different git repositories?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Thanks for answering, wish i could accept all the answers :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would base my decision around whether the applications are to be deployed directly from Git. I would look at a combination of options 2) and 3) - I'd definitely put the license server application into its own repository as it's being deployed to Heroku. I'm not too familiar with Heroku deployment, but it may well deploy everything that's in a specific branch, so if you add all your applications to folders within the same repo, then they'll all be deployed to Heroku together. That may not be what you want.

If different developers/teams work on different applications, they'll find it easier if the applications are in their own separate repositories.

Forget about 1) - a branch is simply a pointer to a commit, so don't add different projects to different branches.

Comment: seperating the heroku app form the others and putting the other projects in sperate folder looks like the way to go.. thanks

Answer (score 7):

> 1. Create a single git repo and put those seperate projects in "branches" ?
> 2. Create a single git repo and just put those projects in seperate fodlers?
> 3. Just put them into different git repositories?

I would go with **2.**.

Depending on the size of your various applications/projects, or how independant they are, you might consider **3**, but it might add too much overhead. Even large repositories are handled very efficiently by git. A single repository also makes the release process easier since you can tag/branch the application as a whole, and do not need to do it on different repositories.

Option **1** is not the way to go - you are using branches usually for feature development, bug fixing and to manage releases. See also [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model).

---

Based on comments and other answers, and if I think about it further, it primarily depends on the **dependencies** between the projects. I would definitely go with **2.** for the Client and the Server applications and most likely also include the Auto Update application.

As others wrote, if the license server is really independent (what about the client part of the license server then?), using a separate repository for this part might be the right solution. My take is that using multiple repositories might complicate the release process, and the process to setup a developer's environment. At the end, the solution might really be the right balance between **2.** and **3.**, based on how dependent or independent the projects are.

Comment: the "." at the end of the link breaks the link :) but i am reading it now

Comment: @Andreas OK, thanks. Now I think that 2 might be better. For example, I developed mobile application for 3 mobile platforms. Every project was on separate git repository. I had 3 computers (Win PC, Mac and Linux for git server). At the end I had all 3 repositories on each of my two development machines and I had to remember to manually pull / push changes and after reading your answer I found that it might be better to have all in one repo. But that was me who was the only, single developer...

Comment: @MichK Yes, if it is **the same application**, but only on **different platforms**, I would in any case use **2** and put the platform specific parts in platform specific sub directories.

Comment: Just jumping into github now, I see that you can choose a gitignore file for the repository as a whole as a function of platform. I assume that if you wanted to combine different platforms in a single repository, you'd also combine their associated gitignore files and hope there are no conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

Humble opinion here:

1. Putting this stuff in branches is definitly wrong, branches of code in git always represent different states of the "same" codebase
2. I wouldn't do that either, though if the two servers and two applications are interdependent enough it might be a good idea to put them in the same repository, that would be my favourite
3. If the 4 applications are disjoint enough that's the way to go.